# Can I give my program an account containing the pubkey of a wallet I want to transfer to, rather than the wallet pubkey itself?

Tags: transfer, sol

My PDA account contains some SOL, and the pubkey of an account I want to transfer the SOL to. Via the client side, is it possible to pass in only the pubkey of the PDA, and then retrieve the receiving account pubkey in the program only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A program endpoint must be provided with the addresses of all the accounts it manipulates. If `recipient` is mutated, you need to pass in `recipient`'s public key.